# Installing R packages on Azure failed: non-zero exit status

Tags: r, azure, azure-databricks

I just started using RStudio on Azure Databricks. After I select the cluster and click on the Libraries tab I managed to install few extra packages (timetk, tidymodels, rules, doFutures). But when I tried to install the modelitme package I got the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Installation failed with message:
> Error installing R package: Could not install package with error: installation of package ‘V8’ had non->zero exit status installation of package ‘rstan’ had non-zero exit status installation of package >‘prophet’ had non-zero exit status installation of package ‘modeltime’ had non-zero exit status Full >error log available at /databricks/driver/library-install-logs/r-package-installation-2020-10->03T10:31:18Z-vcap9s0e.log
>
> Error installing R package: Could not install package with error: installation of package ‘V8’ had non->zero exit status installation of package ‘rstan’ had non-zero exit status installation of package >‘prophet’ had non-zero exit status installation of package ‘modeltime’ had non-zero exit status

How do I solve problem like this?

Comment: Which version of R are you using?

Comment: I'm using R 3.6.3. That was the default version.